# Select and agregate variable for distinct id in SNOWFLAKE SQL

Tags: sql, database, group-by, case, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have SNOWFLAKE database table with customers and their transaction types:

```
customer_id type
1   a
1   a
2   b
2   b
2   b
3   a
3   b
3   a
```

At output I need distinct customer id and type of transaction:

```
customer_id type
1   a
2   b
3   mixed
```

My code does not work:

```
SELECT 
"customer_id",
CASE WHEN type = 'a' THEN "a" 
WHEN type = 'b' THEN "b"
ELSE "mixed" END OVER (PARTITION BY "customer_id" )  AS "type"
FROM CUSTOMERS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need aggregation and a `CASE` expression that checks the number of distinct `type`s of each `customer_id`:

```
SELECT customer_id,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT type) = 1 THEN MAX(type) ELSE 'mixed' END AS type
FROM CUSTOMERS
GROUP BY customer_id;
```

Another way to write the `CASE` expression would be:

```
CASE WHEN MIN(type) = MAX(type) THEN MAX(type) ELSE 'mixed' END AS type
```

I assume that `type` is not nullable.

Comment: Thank you, your solution solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the hardcoded "mixed" is not a must then LISTAGG could be used:

```
SELECT customer_id, LISTAGG(DISTINCT type, ',') AS type
FROM customer
GROUP BY cutomer_id;
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution is great too, I use it at another tasks.